# Excel: How to search for values from a column within a cell that has comma seperated values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, csv

I have one column with text in seperate rows, and a cell that has comma seperated values within the singular cell, as below.

| One | Two |
| --- | --- |
| AB | AB, EF |
| CD | ... |

I'd like a formula to return True if any text in Column 1 appears within the other cell. These cells are actually on different worksheets but I don't see that causing problems.

I'm able to use the SEARCH and CONCAT functions to see if a specific text string is within the cell, however I can't find a way to compare everying from Column 1 with that cell unless I use a very long list of IF functions.

If it helps, the *potential* items that could appear in Column 1 can be pre-defined. The length of the column is variable but will never be greater than 10

I'd rather limit the number of extra cells I need to use with extra formulas as I will be having many different cells that need comparing to the column, although if you recommend a seperate worksheet with lots of assisant formulas, that is possible.

Basically, what's the smallest amount of formulas I need to do to make this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `TWO` is just a single cell as you show, then:

```
=OR(ONE=TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(TWO,",")))
```

where `ONE` is the named range where have your single entries.

Comment: Thank you so much this is perfect!